# CakePHP3, out of permission on logs/ and tmp/

Tags: permissions, cakephp-3.0, chmod

I have got some error of permissions.

[image]

I have set full 777 permission to directory and this work, but hours later, it need to set again, on file of persistent and model folders, on tmp directory...
I have set all day, again and again and again, i dont understand it, the cake create the file with wrong permissions, but dont modify?

UPDATE:
If I delete error.log (or any file on tmp/, for example), the file is re-created with others permissions, giving a permission error... See the imagem. First with permission setting, second the default permission.

[image]

Sorry for bad english.

Comment: what permissions do the files get? and do you switch between command line and browser access to your application?

Comment: Hello @AlexStallen , i can change permission on command line and nautilus, but if i delete error.log (for example), the file is re-created with others permissions... See the imagem. First with permission setting, second the default permission. http://imgur.com/GuAUb8d